# Estimate the mean vector and the covariance matrix using the simple returns

Tags: mean, covariance, covariance-matrix, finance

I would appreciate help with how to to estimate the mean vector and the covariance matrix using the simple returns in R.

I have historical (weekly) values of five stocks from a capital market for a period that covers ten years. And I have used the price data to determine the simple returns on each of these five stocks. Now I want to estimate the mean vector and the covariance matrix using these simple returns.

However, I cannot find any information on how to use the simple returns to do this and neither do I understand that if it should be one mean vector for all five stocks or five different mean vectors - is it someone that want to help me clarify and understand this?

**My initial thoughts:** If we, for example, take the stock BAC (Bank of America Corporation) we can find the mean by `mean(BAC.sr)` where `BAC.sr` is the simple returns of the stock. This gives me the result `0.001083249` but I don't feel like this is the right way since `mean(BAC.sr)` give us the mean of the simple returns of BAC and I don't think this is what the mean vector is.

Answer (score 0):

The mean vector is the the vector of the individual means of the stocks. See example in R with two simple vectors below. Here I used `colMeans` to get the mean vector, and `cov` to get the covariance.

```r
x <- c(2, 4, 6, 20)
y <- c(2, 3, 6, 9)
mat <- cbind(x,y)
mat
      x y
[1,]  2 2
[2,]  4 3
[3,]  6 6
[4,] 20 9 

colMeans(mat)
x y 
8 5 

cov(x,y)
[1] 24
```